# NSNotification: Attempt to present UIAlertController on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller, nsnotification

I'm trying to show a UIAlertController in my ViewController in a function that's been called via an NSNotification. However I'm getting the error:

`Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fe013d05d40> on <submarine.ViewController: 0x7fe011f20370> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

The NSNotification is posted from a completion block (callback I guess) from something else in my UI. Because it's a callback it's failing to display. Hence I thought I'd try NSNotificationCentre to get around the problem without using the rootViewController to display the alert.

My code is:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Handle onboarding
    if needsOnboarding() {
        handleOnboarding() // This create the completion block that posts the NSNotification
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showTermsAlert:", name:"showTermsAlert", object: nil)
}

func showTermsAlert(notification: NSNotification) {
    let termsAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Terms And Conditions", message: "Please view the terms below before accepting them.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    termsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "View Terms", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "my_terms_url")!)
    }))

    termsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I Agree to the Terms", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.onboardingFinished()
    }))

    self.presentViewController(termsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Has anyone got an idea why this is happening? I don't see why it's not in the window hierarchy - it's being presented from the `self` viewController and is created in a top-level function inside the VC.

Thanks!

EDIT: original code inside the `handleOnboarding()`:

Library used: [Onboard](https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard/)

```
func handleOnboarding() {

        let secondPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "What's going on?", body: "Submarine routes your data through our network, around any filters and restrictions, giving you unrestricted and unmonitored internet access.", image: UIImage(named: "back"), buttonText: "Next") { () -> Void in
            // do something here when users press the button, like ask for location services permissions, register for push notifications, connect to social media, or finish the onboarding process
        }
        secondPage.movesToNextViewController = true

        let thirdPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Terms of Use", body: "You must agree to our Terms of Use to use Submarine.\nIf you don't, please close Submarine.", image: UIImage(named: "back"), buttonText: "View Terms") { () -> Void in

            let termsAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Terms And Conditions", message: "Please view the terms below before accepting them.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            termsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "View Terms", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "my_policy_url")!)
            }))

            termsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I Agree to the Terms", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.onboardingFinished()
            }))

            self.presentViewController(termsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

//            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showTermsAlert", object: nil)
        }

        // Image
        let onboardingVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "back"), contents: [secondPage, thirdPage])

        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(onboardingVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen when the presenting view controller is no longer part of the controller hierarchy, and it's view is no longer in the view hierarchy of any window. Most likely, the controller was dismissed or popped, but it heard the notification and attempted to present the alert controller.

You should manage your controller states more carefully. Perhaps remove observer when the controller is dismissed or popped from your controller hierarchy.

Comment: Usually `viewWillDisappear:` method is a good place to remove the observers.

Comment: @Sulthan Maybe it is in this case, maybe not. I specifically did not want to make a specific suggestion, as we don't have enough information. Also, usually a `viewDidAppear:`/`viewWillDisappear:` logic is buggy and often problematic, as we see here.

Comment: @Sulthan so in handleOboarding() I push a new VC onto the NavigationController and then in the callback which occurs after a user action in that controller, I try and show the alert by calling `showTermsAlert()`. Does that clear it up a little?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things i'd change in your code. Add a call to super in `viewDidAppear:`, and stop using the `NSNotification`s for your presentation. You don't know what thread `showTermsAlert` will get called on with this pattern. You can make your intent more explicit by calling `showTermsAlert` directly, and this will also guarantee you're on the main thread.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Handle onboarding
    if needsOnboarding() {
        self.showTermsAlert()
    }
}

func showTermsAlert() {
    let termsAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Terms And Conditions", message: "Please view the terms below before accepting them.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    termsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "View Terms", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "my_terms_url")!)
}))

    termsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I Agree to the Terms", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    self.onboardingFinished()
}))

    self.presentViewController(termsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I can't put it inside the if-block for `needsOnboarding() { }` because the line that was in there (`handleOnboarding()`) creates a new VC, pushes it onto the NavigationController and then does something that creates a call back when it's finished. It's in that callback (after this thing has finished) that I need to call `showTermsAlert()`. Does that clear it up a little?

Comment: ya i think so. based on that, I think that `showTermsAlert()` could be getting called a little too early, before the new VC was fully removed from the screen and window hierarchy? Also make sure you call `self.PresentViewController` on the main thread.

Comment: Just posted an update including the code for `handleOnboarding()` that was how I was trying to do it before NSNotification. I'll have a look at the main thread thing quickly now :)